# Visual C++ - one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++, dll

Whenever I start to build my dll I get this error:
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I think there's nothing wrong with the code because I copied it from a source:

ExoDll1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

double BoxArea(double L, double H, double W);
double BoxVolume(double L, double H, double W);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)void BoxProperties(double Length, double Height,
                                double Width, double& Area, double& Volume);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
    return TRUE;
}

double BoxArea(double L, double H, double W)
{
    return 2 * ((L*H) + (L*W) + (H*W));
}

double BoxVolume(double L, double H, double W)
{
    return L * H * W;
}

void BoxProperties(double L, double H, double W, double& A, double& V)
{
A = BoxArea(L, H, W);
V = BoxVolume(L, H, W);
}
```

I tried to create a new project and delete the old ones but same problem still exists.. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: "I think there's nothing wrong with the code because I copied it from a source." I like optimism a lot.

Comment: I think the source is reliable, it has pictures included in it. Here's the link: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/libraries/staticdll.htm

Comment: Edit the question to include the exact error message(s) (copied using the clipboard). Include the LNK2005 error(s) that should have also been in the build output.  Those may give a clue about where the duplicate symbols are coming from.

Comment: He build the solution without getting an error. is there something wrong with my VC++'s preferences or settings?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong if you don't tell us the actual error.

Answer (score 2):

This error message cannot appear with only a single translation unit (such as `ExoDll1.cpp`).  You might be, for example, unknowingly trying to compile multiple versions of this code simultaneously.

Examine your project and get rid of any source code that you do not want to compile.

Make sure that you do not have `#include "ExoDll1.cpp"` anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes not from the compiler, but from the linker. This means that the compiler found nothing wrong, in particular, no duplicate definitions of symbols *in any one compilation unit*. However, the linker, which generates the .dll library, loads several compilation units and found duplicate definitions of symbols *across compilation units*.

This happens if several compilation units contain the same code with external linkage, i.e. if you `#include`d a source code, or if in a header file (which more than one compilation unit `#include`s) a function was defined and not declared `inline`.